# Can we extend Siddhi CEP java library with Siddhi High Available feature

Tags: wso2, high-availability, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am using Sidhhi CEP as Java library in my project . Now i need to analyse my data with High available system (Similar to Esper HA). I have done little bit study about Siddhi High availability

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/05/high-availability-deployment-in-wso2-complex-event-processor-0/

Also gone through with the above links

is that possible to the same task using Siddhi java library ???

Answer (score 0):

Above document demonstrates how WSO2 CEP has achieved high availability by using multiple nodes with hazelcast clustering. If you are just using Siddhi CEP as a Java library, then you need to implement your clustering by using hazelcast or any other.

More about WSO2 CEP Clustering [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Complex+Event+Processor